# Nonlinear Differential Euqation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following differential equation
\begin{align}
y' = \frac{6-7y-\sqrt{y(24-23y)}}{9\sqrt{1-y}}
\end{align}

with initial condition $y(0) \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$.

- How do I know if there exists an analytically solution?
- And how would you proceed?

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to cancel something out. The correct equation reads
\begin{align}
y' = \frac{6-7y-\sqrt{y(24-23y)}}{9}.
\end{align}

I used the software maxima to solve it, but I don't understand the output.
\begin{align}
q(t) = \textrm{ilt}\left(-\frac{\textrm{laplace}(\sqrt{24q(t)-23q(t)^2},t,s)-6}{7s}, s, t\right)
\end{align}

I think it is somehow related to trigonometric functions?!

EDIT II: With respect to Jan Eerland's answer I used Maxima to integrate the following term 
\begin{align}
&\int{\frac{6-7u + \sqrt{u(24-23u)}}{72u^2 - 108u +36} du} \\[4mm]
=& \int{\frac{\sqrt{24-23u}\sqrt{u}}{72u^2-108u+36}du} + \frac{-5\ln(2u-1)+12\ln(u-1)-14\ln(\sqrt{u}+1)-14\ln(\sqrt{u}-1))}{72}
\end{align}
which gives me a hard time, because there still is an integral in the expression and $\ln(u-1)$ is not defined since $u\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: Show us some of your work, and notice it is a seperable equation

Comment: What are your initial conditions? It would seem you need $0 \leq y \leq \frac{24}{23}$ to make the square root in the numerator Real and you need $y < 1$ to make the square root in the denominator Real and non-zero, which would suggest you're considering $y \in [0,1)$.  How did you come across such an equation? Did you derive it from something? If so, what?

Comment: I added the initial condition. The equation stems from an dynamic optimization problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{6-7y(x)-\sqrt{y(x)(24-23y(x))}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{9}\int1\space\text{d}x$$

Use:

- $$\int1\space\text{d}x=x+\text{C}$$
- For the RHS, substitute $u=y(x)$ and $\text{d}u=y'(x)\space\text{d}x$:

$$\int\frac{1}{6-7u-\sqrt{u(24-23u)}}\space\text{d}u$$

Now rationalize and expand the integrand:

$$\frac{1}{6-7u-\sqrt{u(24-23u)}}=\frac{6-7u+\sqrt{u(24-23u)}}{72u^2-108u+36}$$

**EDIT**

When:

$$\text{I}=\int\frac{y'(x)}{6-7y(x)-\sqrt{y(x)(24-23y(x))}}\space\text{d}x$$

The closed form is:

$$\text{I}=\frac{\sqrt{23}\arcsin\left(1-z\right)-2\left(5\ln|l|+\ln|12-11y(x)+q|\right)+5\ln\left|12+y(x)+5q\right|}{72}$$

Where:

- $$q=\sqrt{y(x)(24-23y(x))}$$
- $$z=\frac{23y(x)}{12}$$
- $$l=1-2y(x)$$

Comment: Okay, thanks. Now I need to integrate the RHS of the last expression?

Comment: @clueless Yes, in order to find the original LHS.

Comment: I'm stuck and have no idea how to continue. Can you confirm that there exists a closed form solution?

Comment: @clueless yes, for the integral exists a close form, do I need to give you the closed from or the way to a closed form?

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could show me how to derive the closed form. My background is econ and I'm only familiar with simple ODEs, i.e., I'm literally clueless. Thanks already for your patience.

Comment: @clueless you're welcome, the way of finding the closed form is hard. So you can use sites like wolframalpha to find it for example.

Comment: Thanks. This is implict right? That is, there is no solution of the form y = f(x)?

Comment: You've to solve $y(x)$ out of those absolute value things and you will not get it that way

Comment: Can I get rid of those absolute value things if I knew that $y\in[0,0.5]$?

Comment: Notice that for $\ln(x)$ the point zero not well defined is!